# Adjust textview and xib frame height based on the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

It is the XIB file (**ChatInputBar.xib**)

[image]

I am trying the update textview's height based on the content and using this code

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;

    if(frame.size.height > textView.frame.size.height){
        CGFloat diff = frame.size.height - textView.frame.size.height;
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y - diff, textView.frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    }
    else if(frame.size.height < textView.frame.size.height){
        CGFloat diff = textView.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y + diff, textView.frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

I get this result

[image]

How can i also update the whole view's height ?

Comment: Is it autolayout?????

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 yes

Comment: may be this will help you https://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2013/11/09/auto-growing-uitextview-using-auto-layout/